# Installing Adobe

Tags: software-installation

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
From the Ubuntu software window I selected "Adobe Acrobat Reader (WINE)" It is now installed but does not run.  In the terminal I can type

```
acrordrdc
```

which gets the following...

```
Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

I assume I need to load something else to get Adobe to work?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need a special feature of Adobe?  Ubuntu has it's own PDF reader, evince, plus there are other linux PDF readers.

Comment: You will need to contact the snap developer. The snap sets up wine. When you start the snap, a script within wine attempts to download and install acrobat within the wine environment set up by the snap, but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same issue with one of my script using dependencies. Inkscape or pdftk.

There you go
`sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module`

Plus, Adobe, even in Wine, isn't pretty much fit for Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you test this also helps for the "Adobe Acrobat Reader (WINE) installation? I do not expect this to work because that is a snap. Dependencies should be provided through the snap system.

Comment: @vanadium : I installed `pdftk` and `inkscape` with Snap on my friend's computer (not mine), she got the same canberra-gtk-module error with her laptop and installing `libcanberra-gtk-module` with the APT did work well. But since it's Wine related, I can't say. OP should give it a try and tell us if it works (or not).

Answer (score 0):

You can download last packages for Ubuntu like .deb of adobe reader 9.5 from [adobe website](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/)

You may also need to Install prerequisites and i386 libraries to be able to install.